Is it possible to wrap @task.kubernetes so it assigns a pod name based on the decorated function name?
I tried creating a decorator that would automatically assign a pod name based on the wrapped function, something like:
def default_kubernetes_task(
    **task_kwargs: Any,
) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], Callable[..., Any]]:
    def decorator(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Any:
        if "name" not in task_kwargs:
            task_kwargs["name"] = f"example-{func.__name__}"

        return task.kubernetes(**task_kwargs)(func)

    return decorator

The pod does get created correctly, however it looks like it runs into an error running the python function, example logs:
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base] + python -c 'import base64, os;x = base64.b64decode(os.environ["__PYTHON_SCRIPT"]);f = open("/tmp/script.py", "wb"); f.write(x); f.close()'
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base] + python -c 'import base64, os;x = base64.b64decode(os.environ["__PYTHON_INPUT"]);f = open("/tmp/script.in", "wb"); f.write(x); f.close()'
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base] + mkdir -p /airflow/xcom
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base] + python /tmp/script.py /tmp/script.in /airflow/xcom/return.json
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base] Traceback (most recent call last):
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base]   File "/tmp/script.py", line 19, in module
{pod_manager.py:468} INFO - [base]     @default_kubernetes_task(
{pod_manager.py:486} INFO - [base] NameError: name 'default_kubernetes_task' is not defined

A colleague and myself traced this to the way the taskflow decorators work, which is to remove the decorator code from the python script that gets run in K8s (source), however, this looks for a fixed operator name defined in the _KubernetesDecoratedOperator class (source).
Is there another way to achieve the goal of automatically assigning pod name based on the decorated function name?
